# How can I automatically add '.s' to a target in my Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a phony `debug` and `asm` target. `debug` works by updating the variable `CFLAGS` and then compiles the normal target, which uses these new `CFLAGS` to produce debug symbols. This works as intended.

Analogously I want to define the `asm` target set the `-S` switch and to change the output name from `file` to `file.s`. However, the last part does not work, and I get:

```
$ make asm -B
gcc -fmessage-length=0 -ansi -pedantic -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Winit-self -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-aliasing -Wformat=2 -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-unused-parameter -Wuninitialized -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdouble-promotion  -S -masm=intel file.c -o file
```

notice the last part `[..] -S -masm=intel file.c -o file` with the extra parameters but without the `.s` extension.

What am I missing?

Makefile:

```
TARGET=file
SOURCE=*.c
HEADERS=*.h
TESTS=*.sh
PROJECT=$(TARGET) $(SOURCE) $(HEADERS) $(TESTS) Makefile
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=\
-ansi \
-pedantic \
-Wall \

# makefile-rules that don't produce files directly
.PHONY: default  all debug asm

default: $(TARGET) 


# Compile 
$(TARGET): $(SOURCE) $(HEADERS) $(TESTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

debug: CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -ggdb
debug: $(TARGET)

asm: CFLAGS +=-S -masm=intel
asm: TARGET +=.s <------------------ THIS LINE !!!!!!
asm: $(TARGET)
```

Comment: `TARGET +=.s` == `file .s`, note the space.

Comment: You can't do it that way because target-specific variables only resolve to those values within the _recipe_ of the rule.  They don't resolve to those values in the prerequisite lists.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html

Comment: @MadScientist You can use secondary expansion and have it resolved in the prerequisite list. The real issue is that you can't do secondary expansion on *target names*, so you'd still have to specify `$(TARGET).s` as an extra target for the CC recipe. And once you do that, it's cleaner to just use `$(TARGET).s` as a prereq for `asm` and skip secondary expansion altogether.

Comment: Yep there are _other_ ways to do it: secondary expansion, eval, etc.  But you can't do it _this_ way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a `$(TARGET).s` target to the rule and use that in `asm`:

```
$(TARGET) $(TARGET).s: $(SOURCE) $(HEADERS) $(TESTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

asm: CFLAGS += -S -masm=intel
asm: $(TARGET).s
```