# Multiple hops in Makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have a C/C++ mixed project and for each source code, I want to generate an assembly file (`.S`) and then an object file (`.o`) from the assembly. I thought the following Makefile should work:

```
all: a.o b.o main.o
    g++ $^ -o main

%.o: %.S
    gcc -o $@ $<

%.S: %.c
    gcc -S -o $@ $<

%.S: %.cc
    g++ -S -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -rf *.o main
```

Ideally, in order to generate `X.o`, `X.S` needs to be generated by using one of the rules depending on whether `X.c` or `X.cpp` is available.

However, `make` apparently doesn't work the way I imagined. It resorts to the default rule for `X.o` and neither `%.S: %.c` nor `%.S: %.cpp` was applied... `make -n` gives

```
cc    -c -o a.o a.c
g++    -c -o b.o b.cc
g++    -c -o main.o main.cc
g++ a.o b.o main.o -o main
```

The following example code can reproduce this:

```
// a.c
int a() { return 0;}

// b.cc
int b() { return 0;}

// main.cc
extern "C" int a();
extern int b();
int main() { a(); b(); return 0; }
```

I must have some misunderstanding of how a target is resolved. Any idea?

Comment: interesting:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572468/how-can-i-automatically-add-s-to-a-target-in-my-makefile

Comment: @LogicStuff: no my apologies. That's indeed a typo. But the problem persists.

Comment: This has been asked multiple times. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39625452/6644919) (replace `.h` with `.c` and `.cc`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the implicit rules as they are a better match, add the following lines

```
%.o: %.cc
%.o: %.c
```

Note that your rule for `all` is broken as it doesn't create a file called `all`, make already knows how to assemble object files from assembly, and it also already knows how to link object files into a program if one of the object files matches the target

```
assembly := a.s b.s main.s
objects  := $(assembly:.s=.o)
.SECONDARY: $(assembly)

main: CC := $(CXX)
main: $(objects)

%.s: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -S -o $@ $<

%.s: %.cc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -S -o $@ $<

%.o: %.cc
%.o: %.c

clean: ; $(RM) $(objects) $(assembly) main
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the better match thing? This would certainly work and is what I had before I want an assembly output.

Comment: I see what you are saying by reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619678/pattern-rule-in-makefile/39625452

Comment: Make will use the shortest possible chain when considering implicit rules, `%.cc` -> `%.o` is one step shorter than `%.cc` -> `%.S` -> `%.o`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.SUFFIXES:` at the top of your Makefile to [flush predefined suffixes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html).  Working example:

```
$tail -n +1 a.c b.cc main.cc Makefile; make clean; make; ./main
==> a.c <==
#include <stdio.h>

void a(void) {
    printf("a\n");
}

==> b.cc <==
#include <stdio.h>

void b(void) {
    printf("b\n");
}

==> main.cc <==
extern "C" {
    void a(void);
}

void b(void);

int main(void) {
    a();
    b();
}

==> Makefile <==
.SUFFIXES:

all: main.o a.o b.o
    g++ $^ -o main # all

%.o: %.S
    gcc -c -o $@ $< #o

%.S: %.c
    gcc -S -o $@ $< #Sc

%.S: %.cc
    g++ -S -o $@ $< #Scc

clean:
    rm -rf *.o main
rm -rf *.o main
g++ -S -o main.S main.cc #Scc
gcc -c -o main.o main.S #o
gcc -S -o a.S a.c #Sc
gcc -c -o a.o a.S #o
g++ -S -o b.S b.cc #Scc
gcc -c -o b.o b.S #o
g++ main.o a.o b.o -o main # all
rm b.S main.S a.S
a
b
```

Comment: A nice complement to `.SUFFIXES:` is also `MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules`.